# Unable to SCP to another IP

Tags: linux, routing, scp

I am attempting to `scp` some files from one IP address to another. I entered the command: `$ scp file baileyd@*IP*:/home/baileyd/doc` and got the response: `ssh: connect to host *IP* port 22: No route to host lost connection`

When I ping to that IP address, I get the message `Destination Host Unreachable`, and when I do a `netstat -ru`, I get 4 lines of text, and then asterisks, meaning that the requests timed out.

From this I conclude that the IP from which I am trying to `scp` the file is unable to connect to the IP to which I want to `scp` the file. I do not have root privileges. Is there a file I should modify or command to execute so that I can connect, or is that something only the system administrator (or someone with root privileges) can do?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a system on the same network as you?

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall `Iptables` is allowed to the source IP, where xx.xx.xx.xx is source IP and to run below rules need root privilege,

> `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s xx.xx.xx.xx --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`

Make sure `SSH` service is running, if not start `SSH` service.

Also Use `nmap <destination IP>` to check the available opened ports.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, I don't have root privilege, so this will be something only our sys admin can do.

Answer (score 0):

"No route to host" indicates that the problem is located on your machine and not on the target. Can you access the target IP from another host?